# CRLF inside XML TAGs

Tags: xml, newline

I've done an android app to process XML files with XMLPullParser. 
Some XML files don't work. They were formatted to be viewed as 80 columns pages.
They have CRLF characters after every 80 characters.
Some CRLF characters are inside TAGs. How can I filter them?

Comment: Then they are not valid XML. Fix your source data. If there's something else, **show your code** and describe your *specific* problem.

Comment: Preprocess the broken document to remove all newlines? That *does* risk changing some legitimate data, since newline is a legal character in text blocks, but it's the only thing I can think of that will work short of strangling the idiot who broke the documents.

Comment: (Pedantic quibble: And the problem is worse than their not being valid -- they aren't even well-formed. I know, you meant "valid" colloquially, and that's a ... ahem ... valid use of the word. I'm just flagging it because the readers are likely to run into this distinction later.)

Answer (score 0):

When you say there are CRLF characters "inside tags", I guess you mean something like

```
<TIT
LE>Introduction</T
ITLE>
```

I ask because unfortunately a lot of people use the word "tag" incorrectly to mean the whole element, and talk of the word "Introduction" is if it is inside a tag, which is not actually the case.

If you have CRLF characters in places where XML does not allow them, then you will have to remove them before passing the data to an XML parser. That doesn't sound very difficult. If you want to do it on the fly you could write an implementation of InputStream that does the filtering, and pass that filtered InputStream to the parser.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Yes, your example is correct. That's my problem. I've tried the following implementation of InputStream : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752622/removing-newline-characters-from-inputstream/14754606#14754606    I get stackoverflow error when the super method is called. How do I correct it?

Comment: Look at the stack trace and see where the infinite recursive loop is happening, then fix it.